# Wish to/Wish in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, direct-objects

> While on the one hand, one does not wish to a state-of-affairs in which ministers are under the cloud of criminal charges, it cannot be denied that there is a serious mixing of criminal investigation and prosecution with politics.

—The Indian Express, July 3,2023

Why not simply '**wish a** state-of-affairs' what's the need for preposition '**to**' here?

Comment: What's the source? Looks like a transcription error to me, or somebody misspoke.

Comment: @gotube The Indian Express Newspaper this Monday paper

Comment: Can you link to it?

Comment: @gotube Well I tried but the article is behind a pay-wall. But here's the link https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/raj-bhavan-raj-dharma-governor-is-to-be-a-wise-counsellor-to-the-cm-which-did-not-happen-in-tamil-nadu-8697890/lite/

Comment: I think, but am not at all sure, that this may be an example of Indian English. I vaguely remember hearing an Indian friend say something like this.  But I can't find any sources.

Comment: That article is behind a paywall, so I can't see the source. Assuming your quote is accurate, all I can say is that it's not correct in any variety of English I'm familiar with, including North American, Caribbean, European, Oceanic or South African. It's possible it's correct in Indian English.